# How to set TabBarView to take up as much vertical space as is available in between two widgets in a Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Column, which has the following widgets inside the column:

```
Column(
  Image[has a fixed height]  
  TabBar[has a fixed height]  
  TabBarView[variable height, expand to take up remaining vertical space]  
  BottomNavigationBar[has a fixed height, and of course is 'pinned' to the bottom of the screen]  
),
```

I need the TabBarView to expand to take up as much space as is available, which will depend on screen size.

Comment: Have you worked with slivers? You can use `CustomScrollView` along with `SliverFillRemaining` to get result

Comment: Never worked with one before, will do some homework on Slivers and see if I can implement something. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It kind of sounds like you should be using a Scaffold as it does most of what you want already. The Image and TabBar could be in their own column in a widget that implements PreferredSizeWidget and would be the `appBar`, the TabBarView would be the `body`, and the BottomNavigationBar would be the `bottomNavigationBar`.

If you're really committed to using a Column, you just need to wrap your TabBarView in an [`Expanded`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have been using a scaffold (e.g. to get the bottomNavigationBar, but not with the Image and TabBar being in the appbar, so will give that a go.  Wrapping in Expanded or Flexible have not worked (something about the TabBarView being set to infinity. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm. Well if scaffold doesn't work, edit your post to add your code (as minimal as reproduces the problem at least) and that will help us figure out exactly what's going on. It sounds like your column might be in something that expands (i.e. a listview) in which case you're going to have trouble using the scaffold as well.